# Are there materials on frontend design system?

Tags: javascript, architecture, frontend, system-design

Has anyone come across the material for designing frontend applications (starting with functional and non-functional requirements). I will give an example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MADCVqL534&t=1171s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utWopFyY5cE

Perhaps there is still usable material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an architecture / design perspective I like to think about the context in which the system / UI will be used:

[image]

...and to consider usability principles:

[image]

Having thought about those, I'd start by designing using pen & paper / whiteboard.  Specifically:

- Screen map / Functional - what pages/screens/widgets are needed, and how they relate.  Be careful in that sometimes you need to think in terms of functionality - not "pages/screens", partly because sometimes functionality might be better encapsulated in a reusable widget that occurs in more than one place.
- Special scenarios - e.g. user registration or some critical functional task.
- Wireframes of screens / widgets, starting with those that will best inform the rest of the design.

I don't have anything for NFR's specifically - where the NFR's inform the design, but I do have some basic "starter" usability requirements:

[image]